# Как поднять сервер QT

Tags: c++, qt, сеть

совсем недавно начал изучать сетевое программирование на QT.Я написал простой чат, состоящий из сервера и клиента и собрал это все на Windows, все работает. Вопрос: Можно ли как то перенести сервер на vds linux?

Comment: Соберите под линуксом

Comment: @Croessmah так если у меня только терминал. А все примеры, которые я нашел, с использованием графического интерфейса

Comment: Линукс и графический интерфейс - не канон) простите, не удержался. Можно, переходите на командные строки и собирайте под линуксом